# How can I add a space after a command in LaTeX3 message?

Tags: spacing, expl3, latex3

I am trying to define a message that includes a computed number.

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 42 }
\msg_new:nnn { package } { message } {
  The~number~ \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int ~is~too~large
}
\msg_error:nn { package } { message }
```

This results in

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! package error: "message"
! 
! The number 42is too large
! 
! See the package documentation for further information.
! 
! Type <return> to continue.
!...............................................
```

Note the missing space after the number. To insert it I could

- make the number an argument, passed when the message is issued. This would take care of the problem in messages, but I suppose it to affect all output material.
- Replacing the space after the number with `\c_space_tl` also works. But this does not look like something `\c_space_tl` was intended for. Is it even save to use `\c_space_tl` or does it have to be wrapped in `\tl_use:N`?

Is there a better or even recommended way to insert a space after such a LaTeX3 command?

Comment: Why isn't `\c_space_tl` good enough? You can also use `\space`...

Comment: @Werner Is `\c_space_tl` just a `\space` clone or does it do fancy stuff besides that?

Comment: @Werner `\space` is not LaTeX3 and looks quite out of place. `\c_space_tl` is from the context of token lists, so I wonder if it is semantically fit here. If the answer is yes, this should be the accepted answer to this question and I have a follow-up: Does it have to be wrapped in `\tl_use:N`?

Comment: @1010011010 Yes, `\c_space_tl` is exactly the same as `\space`.

Comment: @egreg: in a message, "backslash space" (no idea how to put that in a comment) also produces a space, and is the preferred approach (when `~` is not usable).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Thanks for remembering! But I was answering to the question whether `\c_space_tl` is the same as `\space`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the integer control sequence `\l_tmpa_int` is gobbling the explicit spaces after it.

To prevent that behavior, I do think `\c_space_tl` is a good option.
It's definition from my copy of `expl3-code.tex` is

```
\tl_const:Nn \c_space_tl { ~ }
```

So the token list is just a space character wrapped in a control sequence.
After all of the gobbling of the space characters following the control sequence is finished, that `~` is placed into the input stream, and mission accomplished.

The variable `\c_space_tl` is usable on its own since, to quote the API documentation, "it is possible to use a `<tl var>` directly without an accessor function."
I've never run into a situation where `\tl_use:N` was required (not to say it never is) and think it may exist mainly to generate the extremely useful variant `\tl_use:c`.

Another option is to use the counter as the argument to a function that will output the value of the counter.
Three that come to mind are

- `\int_use:c{l_tmpa_int}`
- `\int_eval:n{\l_tmpa_int}`
- `\int_to_arabic:n{\l_tmpa_int}`

With the last one being my favorite due to its extremely explicit nature about what it's doing.

---

Side note: To prevent this in normal text, I'd append an empty group `{}` at the end of the sequence, but that appears to generate a literal `{}` in this context, which is no good.

Answer (score 10):

The fact that spaces disappear after a control sequence is unfortunate but unavoidable (this is the same as when TeX ignores spaces in a document after a command).

In a message, use `\`  (a backslash followed by a space) to produce a space.  You can of course use `\c_space_tl`, but that is longer.

So taking your example, you can do:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 42 }
\msg_new:nnn { package } { message } {
  The~number~ \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int \ is~too~large
}
\msg_error:nn { package } { message }
```

I would advise however to pass the value of `\l_tmpa_int` as an argument to the message:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 42 }
\msg_new:nnn { package } { message } {
  The~number~#1~is~too~large
}
\msg_error:nnx { package } { message } { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
```

This way there is no worry about spaces, and if some day you want to provide different choices of languages for your error message that will let you separate a bit better the message text from the implementation detail of using `\l_tmpa_int`.

Comment: @TroyHaskin is probably right to advise `\int_to_arabic:n`, so the best would probably be to use my second proposal (`\int_use:N\l_tmpa_int` at point of use of the message), but with `\int_to_arabic:n{#1}` in the message's text.

Comment: By the way, `~` is active anyway, so why isn't it let to `\ ` within `\ExplSyntaxOn`?  This way it wouldn't be gobbled by any control sequence.

Comment: @HenriMenke `~` is not active in `\ExplSyntaxOn`.  It has catcode 10.  TeX treats any such character as a space.  Making `~` active would not do the right thing as the token `~` would end up in definitions, and the value used for it would be the one it has when the code is run, typically in `\ExplSyntaxOff` context.